# How to get clientSecret (React) from Stripe Payment Gateway (Woocommerce)

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce, stripe-payments, gatsby

I am using React Stripe Elements in FE (Gatsby.js) and Woocommerce Stripe Payment Gateway Plugin as my BE. My code part which handles it:

```
...
const [checkout] = useMutation<{
    checkout: { order: Order };
  }>(CHECKOUT, {
    onCompleted({ checkout }) {
      handleSuccessfulCheckout({ order: checkout.order });
    },
    onError(error) {
      console.error(error);
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    try {
      const source = (await handleStripe()) as Source;

      await checkout({
        variables: {
          input: {
            paymentMethod: 'stripe',
            shippingMethod: 'Flat rate',
            billing: {
              firstName: shippingInfo.firstName,
              ...
              phone: shippingInfo.phone,
            },
            metaData: [
              {
                key: `_stripe_source_id`,
                value: source.id,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  async function handleStripe(): Promise<Source | Error> {
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      throw Error(`stripe or elements undefined`);
    }

    const cardElements = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    if (!cardElements) {
      throw Error(`Card elements not found`);
    }

    const { source, error: sourceError } = await stripe.createSource(
      cardElements,
      {
        type: 'card',
      }
    );

    if (sourceError || !source) {
      throw Error(sourceError?.message || `Unknown error generating source`);
    }

    return source;
  }

  function handleSuccessfulCheckout({ order }: { order: Order }): void {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      localStorage.removeItem('woo-session');
    }

    const emptyCart: Cart = {
      contents: {
        itemCount: 0,
        nodes: [],
      },
    };

    setCart(emptyCart);
    navigate('/uzsakymas/uzsakymas-gautas', { state: order });
  }
...
```

Somehow this code worked until yesterday, but now all payments stuck at `payment_intent.requires_action`: 3D Secure attempt incomplete

This makes sense, because `stripe.createSource()` is deprecated and I have to use `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` instead. But this method requires `clientSecret`, which I don't know how to get from backend. The `client_secret`, which I can get from `source.client_secret` not working, because it is created like `src_client_secret_2cVpLt70qoh9dJ72kVfHoFSB`, but method requires that `client_secret` would look like this: `pi_3ONoUtKhxv7ffxFk0aPDaV3z_secret_lf7amrXoftevBss6zy5rwhqmq`.

After "succesfull" purchase, Woocommerce plugin fires `payment_intent.created` event, which has `client_secret` correctly formatted, but everything stops at event incoming from Stripe:
`payment_intent.requires_action`. I believe the bug is that inside this event's data:

```
"next_action": {
    "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
    "use_stripe_sdk": {
      "source": "src_1ONoUuKhxv7ffxFkhXTT1zXb",
      "stripe_js": "https://hooks.stripe.com/redirect/authenticate/src_1ONoUuKhxv7ffxFkhXTT1zXb?client_secret=src_client_secret_2cVpLt70qoh9dJ72kVfHoFSB&source_redirect_slug=test_YWNjdF8xT0N2UlhLaHh2N2ZmeEZrLF9QQ0N1VWpKeUdIU01URTA3NUtVS2VYakNsemI3czFh0100f9F8oTeK",
      "type": "three_d_secure_redirect"
    }
  },
```

`stripe_js` uses the wrong `client_secret` (with the `src_client` at the beggining), because I haven't told to do otherwise in FE (not used `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`)

My question how can I get the correct `client_secret` to use inside `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`?

Comment: It depends on the WooCommerce plugin code you use on BE. Speaking from Stripe API perspective, the client secret will come back after a call to create the Payment Intent, as a field in the response: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have no way to retrieve client_secret from Woocommerce plugin. I will need to change tech-stack.